# why i get component must be declared in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to access a function that exists from another schema called cmp.
the call works fine with script :

```
select *  from (cmp.INTERFACES.get_famille_par_cin('WB23476','F00000011324'))
```

but with the following script it causes an error: PLS-00302: Component 'INTERFACES' must be declared

```
set SERVEROUTPUT on
declare
tbl typ_familles:=typ_familles();

begin
tbl:=cmp.INTERFACES.get_famille_par_cin('WB23476','F00000011324');
```

thx for your help !

Comment: did you grant access to the package via a role? grants via roles are not enforced inside pl/sql

Comment: the access is granted by the administrator of the other schema, how can i check?

Comment: Grants via roles are disabled [in *named* PL/SQL blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-privilege-and-role-authorization.html#GUID-8525A4DC-5AD5-4B04-B49E-3568349B3B82), by default; that shouldn't affect an anonymous block. But you can check by doing `set role none` before the `select *` version - if it still works it's a direct grant, if not it's via a role. Are you running both versions as the same user; and does that user have any objects of its own called `CMP`, or is there a private or public synonym with that name?

Comment: set role none; (select *  from (cmp.INTERFACES.get_famille_par_cin('WB23476','F00000011324')))
works fine

Comment: there is no synonyms but i have also package called INTERFACES and function called get_famille_par_cin. functions are duplicated in both schemas

Comment: If the functions are duplicated in both schemas why not call the local one rather than the version in the other schema?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the full error stack?